# Perfect numbers of the form $12m+1$ and $\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{\phi(d)}$, where $\phi(m)$ is Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, totient-function, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

If there are no mistakes combining Exercise 9 a)  (Chapter 3, page 71) and Exercise (Chapter2, page 47) of  *Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* we can prove easily

> **Lemma.** If $n$ is a **perfect number** then 
>   $$2<\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{\phi(d)},$$
>   where $\phi(m)$ is the **Euler's totient function.**

On the other hand, we know the so called **Touchard's theorem.**

> **Question.** Can you give a proof that all integer $n\geq 3$ of the form $n=12m+1$ satisfies 
>   $$\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{\phi(d)}\leq 2?$$ 
>   Or well can you find a counterexample (I say with a computer), an integer $n\geq 3$ such that $n\equiv 1\mod 12$ satisfying $\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{\phi(d)}> 2?$ **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I'm interesting by two reasons: first since in the case that you can find the proof, then by contradiction we can prove that there are no odd perfect numbers of the form $12m+1$; and secondly since in 2007, May I sent this question to a journal, I don't know if it was published, I believe that not at 99.99%, and I don't know if there were mistakes in my computations or these were not interesting for the journal, or well these computations were in the literature at those date (I say only as curiosity, since after these years I don't want contact a twice time with the journal.)

Comment: **I say that I only sent to a journal of my country, the proof of previous Lemma, I don't know how solve the Question.** Neither I don't know if these Lemma and Question is in the literature.

Comment: Thanks Martin Sleziak for your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest counterexamples are $37182145$, $56581525$, $61686625$, $92317225$, $96521425$, $107632525,\dots$.

For example, for $37182145=5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23$,
your sum has value $\frac{676039}{331776}$ which is about 2.0376.

Comment: Then possibly they communicated this fact: there are counterexamples, I don't remember well if the journal say me this fact. Very thanks much, today I only tested with my computer until $10^4$. Very thanks also by the factorization.